# Algorithm for generating a unique ID in C++?

Tags: c++, uniqueidentifier

What can be the best algorithm to generate a unique id in C++?
The length ID should be a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: Unique in what sense - on your machine, in your application?

Comment: SLaks - how can you say that without knowing his requirements? And since when is a GUID 32 bits?

Comment: To be honest,what is the difference between the two of them?

Comment: Provide more information. The length of the ID a 32-bit integer - does this mean a 4-billion-digit ID? Unlikely.

Comment: sorry,if i wrote incorrectly,it should be a 32 bit number. did you interpret 32 * 32 bit?

Comment: @Ajay: as for the differene - if that's in your application then a simple counter will do the job. If that's on the machine then you want it unique even between different processes running the same program, and this is more difficult.

Comment: GUID is windows specific API, not cross platform...

Answer (score 69):

Getting a unique 32-bit ID is intuitively simple: the next one.  Works 4 billion times.  Unique for 136 years if you need one a second.  The devil is in the detail: what was the previous one?  You need a reliable way to persist the last used value and an atomic way to update it.

How hard that will be depends on the scope of the ID.  If it is one thread in one process then you only need a file.  If it is multiple threads in one process then you need a file and a mutex.  If is multiple processes on one machine then you need a file and a named mutex.  If it is multiple processes on multiple machines then you need to assign a authoritative ID provider, a single server that all machines talk to.  A database engine is a common provider like that, they have this built-in as a feature, an auto-increment column.

The expense of getting the ID goes progressively up as the scope widens.  When it becomes impractical, scope is Internet or provider too slow or unavailable then you need to give up on a 32-bit value.  Switch to a random value.  One that's random enough to make the likelihood that the machine is struck by a meteor is at least a million times more likely than repeating the same ID.  A goo-ID.  It is only 4 times as large.

Comment: Nice answer for the overview of the problem, any pointers to a standard method for the last solution, with the random number? What is a good practical approach to generate good enough random numbers?

Comment: Maybe you were referring to "UUID", as described by this wikipedia article?         http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: Yes.  Whether a number is globally unique (guid) or universally unique (uuid) is something I don't want to touch with a ten-foot pole.  It is a big universe out there :)

Answer (score 15):

Here's the simplest ID I can think of.

```
MyObject obj;
uint32_t id = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(&obj);
```

At any given time, this ID will be unique across the application. No other object will be located at the same address. Of course, if you restart the application, the object may be assigned a new ID. And once the object's lifetime ends, another object may be assigned the same ID.

And objects in different memory spaces (say, on different computers) may be assigned identical IDs.

And last but not least, if the pointer size is larger than 32 bits, the mapping will not be unique.

But since we know nothing about what kind of ID you want, and how unique it should be, this seems as good an answer as any.

Comment: Bad idea. Imagine a 64 bits application. There is a very large chance that 32 bits of that address will be 0x00000000, or at least the same for all object addresses in a program. (Note: truncating reinterpret_cast results are likely to depend on endianness)

Comment: I already pointed that out. If the pointer size is larger than 32 bits, you'll get collisions. But since we know virtually nothing about what the ID is needed for, or in which type of application, I just wanted to suggest the simple and obvious solution.

Comment: Is there a way for this to accommodate this to work for 64 bits and 32 bits?

Comment: Be careful with this method. I used the same approach and when you remove your object and create new, new object can has the same address. It is too dangerous if you have multi-threading application.

Answer (score 8):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524/unique-id-c). (Complete answer, I think, is on Stack Overflow.)
Some note for unique id in C++ in Linux in [this site](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread105540.html). And you can use uuid in Linux, see this man [page and sample](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/fonctions_bibliotheques/ossp/uuid2) for this.

If you use windows and need windows APIs, see this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651782%28VS.71%29.aspx).

This Wikipedia page is also useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
DWORD uid = ::GetTickCount();
::Sleep(100);
```

Comment: Sorry, in theory, if two machines do this on the same time - both machine will get the same uid, so the number is not unique across computers. See Neil's comment to the main question. It's correct if the demand is only to get uniqueness on the same machine across time, and not uniqueness across machines.

Comment: Plus GetTickCount() is not very precise.  You could call it three times in a row and get the same response.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to use Boost, then there is a [UUID](http://www.boost.org/libs/uuid) library that should do the trick. It's very straightforward to use - check the documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248017/61574).

Comment: Including an entire library just for one problem probably isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is little context, but if you are looking for a unique ID for objects within your application you can always use a singleton approach similar to

```
class IDGenerator {
   public:
      static IDGenerator * instance ();
      uint32_t next () { return _id++; }
   private:
      IDGenerator () : _id(0) {}

      static IDGenerator * only_copy;
      uint32_t _id;
}

IDGenerator *
IDGenerator::instance () {
   if (!only_copy) {
      only_copy = new IDGenerator();
   }
   return only_copy;
}
```

And now you can get a unique ID at any time by doing:

`IDGenerator::instance()->next ()`

Comment: static IDGenerator &instance ()  
{  
  static IDGenerator Generator;  
   return Generator;  
}

Comment: Original answer allows for destruction of the singleton. Local static var is faster to implement but you lose that option.