# Example of UUID generation using Boost in C++

Tags: c++, boost, uuid, boost-uuid

I want to generate just random UUID's, as it is just important for instances in my program to have unique identifiers. I looked into [Boost UUID](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/index.html), but I can't manage to generate the UUID because I don't understand which class and method to use.

I would appreciate if someone could give me any example of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

A basic example:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            // uuid class
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> // generators
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>         // streaming operators etc.

int main() {
    boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
    std::cout << uuid << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

> 7feb24af-fc38-44de-bc38-04defc3804de

Comment: And how would you assign it to a string? Because I have a common base for every instance and I would need to concatenate UUID to a base. Thanks again!

Comment: @nik: Use the [streaming support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp) - there is a `stringstream` example. Or let `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(uuid)` do that for you.

Comment: As for the double parantheses: The first constructs an instance of `random_generator`, the second uses `operator()` on that instance. You should save the generator and call `operator()` on it if you want to generate more than one uuid: `random_generator rg; uuid ui = rg();`

Comment: @Nikola : use boost::uuids::to_string(uuid) for stringifying uuids

Comment: What is the generated UUID in the example based on? I want my UUID to include the network address and time.

Comment: @danijar: That's a [random one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29). Why do you need to include them? Can't you use/store those two values additionally if you really need them?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche Together, exact time and machine's individual network address is uniquely. I though therefore it might be good key for the hash function. I don't need the clear values later on. But your idea has brought me an idea. It might be a good to use time and network address as seed for the random number generator or so.

Comment: @danijar: For practical purposes UUIDs can be considered unique - isn't that enough? Sounds like you really want to ask the question if the random generator that boost::uuids defaults to here is good enough for your usecase. I'd ask about that specifically and just use another one if it isn't.

Answer (score 43):

The answer of Georg Fritzsche is ok but maybe a bit misleading. You should reuse the generator if you need more than one uuid.
Maybe it's clearer this way:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            // uuid class
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> // generators
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>         // streaming operators etc.


int main()
{
    boost::uuids::random_generator generator;

    boost::uuids::uuid uuid1 = generator();
    std::cout << uuid1 << std::endl;

    boost::uuids::uuid uuid2 = generator();
    std::cout << uuid2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should you re-use the generators?  Is this a performance optimization or a safety tip?

Comment: It wouldn't be a very good universally unique ID if using a new generator caused uniqueness problems.

Comment: @xaxxon Do you have any documentation regarding the uniqueness problem when creating new generator.

Comment: @Saneeshkumar It's a "universally unique identifier" not a "this generator unique identifier" for a reason.

Comment: Learn from me and make generators thread local. They're very expensive to seed

Comment: The official documentation only encourage to reuse a random_generator for performance sake, not safetiness.  "Depending on the platform there may be a setup cost in initializing the generator so plan to reuse it if you can"  _Source_: [Boost uuid 1.70.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/uuid/doc/uuid.html#Synopsis_random_generator)