# How to generate GUID using standard c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

In standard c++, how to generate GUID?

In windows, I know I have API to create. But I would like to be platform independent, is there a way?

Comment: Not in standard C++11.

Comment: @cyber: That linked question specifically asks for a Windows solution!

Comment: There must be a standard and recommendations. I would google for UUID. Maybe start with Wikipedia.

Comment: Check this link. It might help you to solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247861/example-of-uuid-generation-using-boost-in-c/3248017#3248017

Comment: You could try [Boost.Uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/uuid/)

Answer (score 2):

The [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) refers to Microsoft's implementation of the Universal Unique IDentifier (UUID) defined by [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

So for the Microsoft implementation there is no portable way to generate it: it's windows API. It's 16 bytes as UUID, but there are some differences in the byte order.

But if you are looking for UUID,  [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/uuid/) provides a portable implementation.